# Conditionally apply a function in Scala - How to write this function?

Tags: scala

I need to conditionally apply a function f1 to the elements in a collection depending on the result of a function f2 that takes each element as an argument and returns a boolean. If f2(e) is true, f1(e) will be applied otherwise 'e' will be returned "as is".
My intent is to write a general-purpose function able to work on any kind of collection.

```
c: C[E] // My collection 
f1 = ( E => E )  // transformation function
f2 = ( E => Boolean )  // conditional function
```

I cannot come to a solution. Here's my idea, but I'm afraid I'm in high-waters

```
/* Notice this code doesn't compile ~ partially pseudo-code */
conditionallyApply[E,C[_](c: C[E], f2: E => Boolean, f1: E => E): C[E] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def loop(a: C[E], c: C[E]): C[E] = {
    c match {
      case Nil => a // Here head / tail just express the idea, but I  want to use a generic collection
      case head :: tail => go(a ++ (if f2(head) f1(head) else head ), tail)
    }
  }
  loop(??, c)  // how to get an empty collection of the same type as the one from the input?
}
```

Could any of you enlighten me?

Comment: why not map with x => if (f2(x)) f1(x) else x

Comment: Yes, you're right... the solution is very simple

Comment: If you actually want to write a function that can do this, I can write a fancy answer using `CanBuildFrom` etc. But it seems overkill.

Comment: @Lucas that is essentially my answer, just do it inline.

Comment: @andyczerwonka It wasn't before you edited it. Looks right now though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a simple `map` of a `Functor`. Using `scalaz`:

```
def condMap[F[_],A](fa: F[A])(f: A => A, p: A => Boolean)(implicit F:Functor[F]) =
  F.map(fa)(x => if (p(x)) f(x) else x)
```

Comment: I don't want to use scalaz, but this is a good starting point.

Comment: This also addresses your requirement for any collection, here it's for any type constructor needing a single type. e.g: List / Array / Tree etc

Comment: Wouldn't be enough declaring the collection as Iterable[E] ?

Comment: `Iterable[A]` is a terrible abstraction, as you lose type information. It's strictly speaking less powerful than using a typeclass - in this case, `Functor` correctly expresses the requirement to transform values in the structure.

Comment: I'll read more about it... as you may have realized, I'm a starter on FunProg and Scala

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you would need scalaz for something so pedestrian.

```
// example collection and functions
val xs = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: Nil
def f1(v: Int) = v + 1
def f2(v: Int) = v % 2 == 0                     

// just conditionally transform inside a map
val transformed = xs.map(x => if (f2(x)) f1(x) else x)
```

Comment: This result is not the same length as the original now.

Comment: Yes, because you're only getting the ones that pass through the filter. You can reverse it and map over the entire collection and selectively execute f1. I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: That's not what I want: I don't aim at filtering the elements in the collection, but just transform some of them that satisfy a given condition and keep the others as they are

Comment: The code does exactly that, only transforms the elements that satisfy the condition. They must be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Without using scalaz, you can use the `CanBuildFrom` pattern. This is exactly what is used in the standard collections library. Of course, in your specific case, this is probably over-engineered as a simple call to `map` is enough.

```
import scala.collection.generic._

def cmap[A, C[A] <: Traversable[A]](col: C[A])(f: A ⇒ A, p: A ⇒ Boolean)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[C[A], A, C[A]]): C[A] = {
  val b = bf(col)
  b.sizeHint(col)
  for (x <- col) if(p(x)) b += f(x) else b += x
  b.result
}
```

And now the usage:

```
scala> def f(i: Int) = 0
f: (i: Int)Int

scala> def p(i: Int) = i % 2 == 0
p: (i: Int)Boolean

scala> cmap(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4))(f, p)
res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 0, 3, 0)

scala> cmap(List(1, 2, 3, 4))(f, p)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 0, 3, 0)

scala> cmap(Set(1, 2, 3, 4))(f, p)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 0, 3)
```

Observe how the return type is always the same as the one provided.

The function could be nicely encapsulated in an implicit class, using the "pimp my library" pattern.

Comment: I'd like you to provide further details about the idea of "over-engineering": is there a way to get what I asked without using CBF? if it is the case, I will appreciate if you review your post providing an alternative for a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this you can use an implicit class. They were added just for this reason, to enhance libraries you can't change.

It would work like this:

```scala
object ImplicitStuff {
  implicit class SeqEnhancer[A](s:Seq[A])  {
    def transformIf(  cond : A => Boolean)( f : A => A ):Seq[A] =
      s.map{ x => if(cond(x)) f(x)  else x }
  }

  def main(a:Array[String]) = {
    val s = Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

    println(s.transformIf(_ % 2 ==0){ _ * 2})
    // result is (1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12, 7)
  }
}
```

Basically if you call a method that does not exists in the object you're calling it in (in this case, `Seq`), it will check if there's an implicit class that implements it, but it looks like a built in method.